# call a class from a collection_action in ActiveAdmin (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in ruby on rails. I'm trying to call a class from a `collection_action` in ActiveAdmin. Here is the code(app/admin/models):

```
collection_action :status_race, :method => :post do
    #Do some import work..
    redirect_to :class => :import_route
end
```

And this is the code of the class I want to call(app/lib/route):

```
class ImportRoute
def  initialize
    @seperator = " "
    @time_format = "%d-%m-%y"
end
def run(filename)
    puts "Running route import file"

    raise "File" + filename + "doesn't not exist" unless File.exist(filename)

    ri = RouteImporter.find(:name => self.class.name)

    if(ri.nil?)
        puts "Error, file doesn't exists"
    end
    CSV.foreach(filename, {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|
        if row.lenght >5
            ri.country_name = row[0] + " " + row[1]
            ri.type = row[2]
            ri.company = row [3]
        else
            ri.country_name = row[0]
            ri.type = row[1]
            ri.company = row[2]
            ri.date = row[4].gsub(";", " ")
        end
    end
end
```

end

I was using `redirect_to` to call the class but is not working, and I don't have any clue about how to do it. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is taken from http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#collection_actions

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  collection_action :import_csv, :method => :post do
    # Do some CSV importing work here...
    redirect_to {:action => :index}, :notice => "CSV imported successfully!"
  end
end
```

> This collection action will generate a route at
>   “/admin/posts/import_csv” pointing to the
>   Admin::PostsController#import_csv controller action.

So it means you have to add a method import_csv in app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb. Inside this method, you can instantiate your model:

```
def import_csv
  import_route = ImportRoute.new
  # do stuff on this object
end
```

You can easily adapt this to your code

Comment: Thanks! just few questions, what :index means there? In my case will be something like :action => :import_route? I don't have any class called pos_controller.rb

Comment: I neither have a posts file inside admin

Comment: Finally I solved it adding ImportRoute.new to the collection action without redirect_to, for the moment is not complaining!

Comment: :index is the name of the action (method) you will be redirected after  the import of the CSV data is done in the method import_csv. RFC2616 says, that after every POST a redirect to a GET resource should be made ...